# grep for special characters in Unix

Tags: unix, search, grep, special-characters

I have a log file (application.log) which might contain the following string of normal & special characters on multiple lines:

```
*^%Q&$*&^@$&*!^@$*&^&^*&^&
```

I want to search for the line number(s) which contains this special character string.

```sh
grep '*^%Q&$*&^@$&*!^@$*&^&^*&^&' application.log
```

The above command doesn't return any results.

What would be the correct syntax to get the line numbers?

Comment: `^@` : means `^` followed by `@` or nul character?

Answer (score 218, accepted):

Tell `grep` to treat your input as fixed string using `-F` option.

```sh
grep -F '*^%Q&$*&^@$&*!^@$*&^&^*&^&' application.log
```

Option `-n` is required to get the line number,

```sh
grep -Fn '*^%Q&$*&^@$&*!^@$*&^&^*&^&' application.log
```

Comment: Depending your version of grep you only need to escape (with a backslash) `^`, `$`, `.`, `*` and `\ `. or you can try `fgrep`, too.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul: +1. btw, `fgrep` is same as `grep -F`.

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley: it's the same but on some systems there are many versions of grep so using fgrep may find the version which support -F

Comment: What if he use `egrep '*^%Q&$*&^@$&*!^@$*&^&^*&^&' application.log` ?

Comment: Doesn't work. `grep -rinF '-static'` prints `Invalid option «t»`. The @Mani's [answer worked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12406009/2388257), i.e. `grep -rin "\-static"`.

Comment: Did not work for me on MacOs. Maybe considering specifying your environment in the answer?

Comment: Did not work on Ubuntu 20.04.5 with `grep -Fn '#!/usr/bin/python' --include=*.py`, no any output shown and seems stucked in console.

Answer (score 132):

The one that worked for me is:

```sh
grep -e '->'
```

The -e means that the next argument is the pattern, and won't be interpreted as an argument.

From: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/how-to-grep-for-string-769460/

Comment: str='! " # $ % & ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~' ; echo "$str" | grep -e "$str"  ..... NOT WORKING, what worked for you didn't had enough special characters besides switch sign '-', but win -F instead of -e is WORKING !

Comment: The only thing works for me, even '\' or -F or fgrep do not work. Thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - simple and works for grep

Comment: Tried -F and fgrep doesn't work for me when searching a string include '-' char. This works.

Comment: I'm wondering why this answer is present in this question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/12387685 for reference to Q&A I'm currently viewing) - probably a wrong case of answers getting merged from another question? To search for patterns starting with `-`, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427913/how-can-i-grep-for-a-string-that-begins-with-a-dash-hyphen

Comment: please mark this one as the accepted answer. The -F option (currently marked as the accepted doesnot work)

Comment: This works, not -F, not fgrep. Tested on MacOS Catalina

Comment: This works for me on a Mac

Comment: trying to find all pointers of pointers in the c file with `grep  -e "->*->" a.c` doesn't seem to work . the * picks up all sorts of garbage. any suggestions ?

Answer (score 9):

#### A related note

To grep for carriage return, namely the `\r` character, or `0x0d`, we can do this:

```
grep -F $'\r' application.log
```

Alternatively, use `printf`, or `echo`, for POSIX compatibility

```
grep -F "$(printf '\r')" application.log
```

And we can use `hexdump`, or `less` to *see* the result:

```
$ printf "a\rb" | grep -F $'\r' | hexdump -c
0000000   a  \r   b  \n
```

Regarding the use of `$'\r'` and other supported characters, see [Bash Manual > ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting):

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially. The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard

Answer (score 3):

```sh
grep -n "\*\^\%\Q\&\$\&\^\@\$\&\!\^\@\$\&\^\&\^\&\^\&" test.log
1:*^%Q&$&^@$&!^@$&^&^&^&
8:*^%Q&$&^@$&!^@$&^&^&^&
14:*^%Q&$&^@$&!^@$&^&^&^&
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try removing any alphanumeric characters and space. And then use `-n` will give you the line number. Try following:

`grep -vn "^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$" application.log`

Comment: Thanks.. It's works good for me to find the special characters from a file.

Answer (score -4):

Try vi with the -b option, this will show special end of line characters
(I typically use it to see windows line endings in a txt file on a unix OS)

But if you want a scripted solution obviously vi wont work so you can try the -f or -e options with grep and pipe the result into sed or awk.
From grep man page:

Matcher Selection
       -E, --extended-regexp
              Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (ERE, see below).  (-E is specified by POSIX.)

```
   -F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.  (-F is specified
          by POSIX.)
```

Comment: In what way this is better than an accepted answer so you added it to almost 5-years old question?