# How to make grep interpret a search expression ignoring all special characters

Tags: regex, search, grep

I'd like to search for an html string which contains characters interpreted by grep as special characters. Is there a flag or command which will tell grep to interpret all characters in the search string as literal characters, NOT as special characters?

Perfect world:

```
grep --ignorespecial '<a href="/abc/def" class="foo.bar"/>'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grep for special characters in Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387685/grep-for-special-characters-in-unix)

Comment: Can you clarify? "search for a html string which contains multiple special characters" and "tell grep to ignore all special characters and search for the 'literal' string?" seem to contradict each other

Comment: OK Go easy on me people - I did find the answer I was looking for for which I'm grateful... I want to search the term inside the quotes, ignoring all special characters. Am I missing something? Is there a more clear way to ask the question? Is this a 'stupid question'?

Comment: The phrase "ignoring all special characters" is unclear. I think you mean that searching for `foo*bar` should match `foo*bar`, but it could mean that `foo*bar` should match `foobar`. Rather than *ignoring* special characters, I think you mean to say that you want to treat them as non-special characters. (Which is exactly what `fgrep` does.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! Use `grep -F`.

From `man grep`:

> **-F**, --fixed-strings
>
> Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines,
>   any of which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by POSIX.)

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello
<a href="/abc/def" class="foo.bar"/>my href</a>

<a href="/abc/def/ghi" class="foo.bar"/>

$ grep -F '<a href="/abc/def" class="foo.bar"/>' a
<a href="/abc/def" class="foo.bar"/>my href</a>
```

Or with more bash codes:

```
$ cat a
hello
<a href="/abc/def" class="foo.bar"/>my href</a>

This is/ a $line with some ^codes * yeah

$ grep 'This is/ a $line with some ^codes * yeah' a   # no -F, no matches
$

$ grep -F 'This is/ a $line with some ^codes * yeah' a # -F, matches
This is/ a $line with some ^codes * yeah
```

Comment: Or, equivalently, `fgrep`