# grep search for specific text and exclude 2 urls containing that text

Tags: shell, unix, grep, command

I'm trying to do a PuTTY search for a specific text "Omega". But I want to exclude two specific URLs that also contain the text "Omega".

I have tried:

```
grep -ril "Omega" --exclude='<p> | <a href="www.omega.com"> Omega</a> |</p>' --exclude='<li><a href ="www.omega.com"> Omega</a></li>'
```

Also tried:

```
grep -ril "Omega" --exclude={<p> | <a href=" www.omega.com"> Omega</a> |</p>,<li><a href ="www.omega.com" target="_blank">Omega</a></li>}
```

Note the 2 pipes in one of the excludes is a divider for my navigation menu. 
I'm trying write the results to a log file. I'm not generating the results that I need.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution:

```
grep <your_search> | grep -v <url1> | grep -v <url2>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm new to stack overflow and my post didn't set up right because of the href's
So I have one url that is has pipes ' | <ahref>Omega</a> |' how can I include the pipes without it being an "or" . Would that matter, since it is inside of quotations?

Comment: There is even simpler way by using: `grep -ve <url1> -e <url2>`.

Comment: @nicban you can always use grep -vF. -F tells it to treat string in quotes as a fixed string.
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387685/grep-for-special-characters-in-unix

Answer (score 1):

I would use `awk` for this:

```
awk -v pat1='<a href="www.omega.com"> Omega</a> |</p>' 
    -v pat2='<li><a href ="www.omega.com"> Omega</a></li>' 
    '/Omega/ && $0 !~ pat1 && $0 !~ pat2' file
```

With this, we are matching those lines that contain `Omega` but do not contain the patterns you indicate in the question.

Note that you `grep --exclude` is not the way to go, since `exclude` affects files, not patterns.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
Omega
<p> | <a href="www.omega.com"> Omega</a> |</p>
<li><a href ="www.omega.com"> Omega</a></li>'
my Omega
$ awk -v pat1='<a href="www.omega.com"> Omega</a> |</p>' -v pat2='<li><a href ="www.omega.com"> Omega</a></li>' '/Omega/ && $0 !~ pat1 && $0 !~ pat2' a
Omega
my Omega
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing html code without a dedicated parser is painful. If you cannot clean the input for grep, use a dedicated [HTML Parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_parsers)

If you could clean the code, then it should be as simple as:

```
# nice input ahead
> cat omega_sites.txt 
www.exclude1_omega.com
www.exclude1_omega.com
www.my_precious_omega.com
www.all_but_omega.org
www.just_alpha.net

# filter exclude1 and exclude2 
# and redirect using tee to a log file 
> grep -i omega omega_sites.txt | grep -v -i "exclude1\|exclude2" | tee omega_sites_filtered.txt
www.my_precious_omega.com
www.all_but_omega.org
>
```