# Using grep to search in the files for word with '='

Tags: bash, grep

I can search for a word in the file by using `grep` for example:

```
grep 'total energy' file*
```

but I can't search for a word with `=`, for example:

```
grep 'total energy =' file*
```

Why? is there any solution to above issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grep for special characters in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387685/grep-for-special-characters-in-unix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use double quotes (`""`) like this

```
grep "total energy =" /your/file
```

where you substitute `/your/file` with the name of your file. Read [difference between `""` and `''`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash).

---

To search through all files in current directory, you want the next command

```
find ./ -type f -exec grep "total energy =" {} \;
```

What this does is it first finds all files in current dir using `find` (`./` denotes current directory, `-type f` stands for only files). Then it executes `grep` search for `"total energy ="`. `\` denotes where the end of `-exec` is, in case there would be anything else behind it.

If you only want to search through files that are like `frame[number].inp`, you can use regex with `find`:

```
find ./ -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*?\.inp' -exec grep "total energy =" {} \;
```

Comment: maybe because I have many files ( from frame0.inp to frame310.inp)?

Comment: Oh, you want to search multiple files? I edited the answer and included the command to search all files in current directory.

Comment: also not , when I remove = , it works well with your answer.

Comment: That is very very strange... What OS and what shell are you running? I am running BASH on Ubuntu 14.04...

Comment: yep, i corrected my mistake... forgot posix regex doesn't use wildcards. check answer. also https://prnt.sc/gh01wu