# Print a dash if grep not found

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I would like this command to print a dash if grep not found (in addition to the new line already coded):

```
while read vl ; do grep -w "$vl" APL_vs_HS.tab || printf "\n" ; done < 1
```

Thanks! Bernardo

Comment: By "grep not found", do you mean that the `grep` command doesn't exist, or that `grep` doesn't find the pattern? I presume the latter, but the way you phrased it implies the former.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you need to use `printf`? Simply use `echo`, then you won't need to worry about printing a newline because `echo` automatically outputs one.

```
while read vl ; do grep -w "$vl" APL_vs_HS.tab || echo "-" ; done < 1
```

Answer (score 4):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427913/how-can-i-grep-for-a-string-that-begins-with-a-dash), so that one would do

```
while read vl; do grep -w "$vl" APL_vs_HS.tab || printf -- "-\n" ; done < 1
```