# How can I grep for a string that contains multiple consecutive dashes?

Tags: regex, grep

I want to `grep` for the string that contains with dashes like this:

```
---0 [58ms, 100%, 100%]
```

There's at least one dash.

I found this question: [How can I grep for a string that begins with a dash/hyphen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427913/how-can-i-grep-for-a-string-that-begins-with-a-dash-hyphen)

So I want to use:

```
grep -- -+ test.txt
```

But I get nothing.

Finally, my colleague tells me that this will work:

```
grep '\-\+' test.txt
```

Yes, it works. But neither he nor I don't know why after searched many documents.

This also works:

```
grep -- -* test.txt
```

Comment: as far as I know, when you drop quotes, you string `-+` is first interpreted by bash, but with the quotes it passed untouched to the grep command itself, where it is interpreted like a perl regex

Comment: I know this is not a complete answer, but it is a sort of a pointer to the real cause

Comment: the `+` sign indicates at least one occurrence of the previous character, also add `^` to indicate beginning of line. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Syntax

Comment: What file does grep list the match in if you run `grep -H -- -* * test.txt`? Does it find it in `test.txt` or some other file? Does `grep -- -\\+ test.txt` work (this is the same as `grep -- '-\+' test.txt`)?

Comment: Sorry , redundant star

Comment: yeah! `grep -- -\\+ test.txt` works! why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `-+` you are saying: multiple `-`. But this is not understood automatically by `grep`. You need to tell it that `+` has a special meaning.

You can do it by using an extended regex `-E`:

```
grep -E -- "-+" file
```

or by escaping the `+`:

```
grep -- "-\+" file
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
---0 [58ms, 100%, 100%] 
hell
$ grep -E -- "-+" a
---0 [58ms, 100%, 100%] 
$ grep -- "-\+" a
---0 [58ms, 100%, 100%]
```

---

From `man grep`:

> REGULAR EXPRESSIONS
>
> Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions
>
> In  basic  regular  expressions  the  meta-characters  ?,  +,  {, |,
>   (, and ) lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed
>   versions \?, \+, \{, \|, \(, and \).

Comment: @haithink `+` is treated differently. It is a meta-character, as described in the man page. See my update.

Comment: @haithink thanks for the edit! I didn't notice the backslashes weren't showing properly. Also, remember you can always accept an answer when your question is solved.