# Using grep to find a string which contains a command

Tags: search, grep

How do I use grep to search for "-f". it seems to interpret this as an option in the grep command rather than an actual string.

```
 arecord --help | grep "-f"
```

I want to be able to search through the argument options for the arecord command

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I grep for a string that begins with a dash/hyphen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427913/how-can-i-grep-for-a-string-that-begins-with-a-dash-hyphen)

Comment: yes it does, thank you