# How can I add quotes to a grep command in a makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to check for the presence of available compiler warning flags in my makefile.

Here is my first attempt:

```
HAS_WARNING     = $(shell $(CXX) --help=warnings | grep $(1))
HAS_FLOAT_CONV := $(call HAS_WARNING,-Wfloat-conversion)

$(error "has=$(HAS_FLOAT_CONV)")
```

If I run this through make with `bash -x` enabled, I can see the search term passed to `grep` is not quoted, and so the initial `-` is treated as an option:

```
$ make SHELL="/bin/bash -x" 
+ g++ --help=warnings
+ grep -Wfloat-conversion
grep: invalid option -- 'W'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
makefile:10: *** "has=".  Stop.
```

I need to somehow add quotes around my search term.

Everything I've tried has come up short:

**Passing the search term in quotes:**

```
HAS_WARNING = $(shell $(CXX) --help=warnings | grep "$(1)")
```

Result: No quotes added:

```
$ make SHELL="/usr/bin/bash -x" 
+ g++ --help=warnings
+ grep -Wfloat-conversion
grep: invalid option -- 'W'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
makefile:10: *** "has=".  Stop.
```

**Passing the search term in escaped quotes:**

```
HAS_WARNING = $(shell $(CXX) --help=warnings | grep \"$(1)\")
```

Result: The search term is passed in quoted quotes:

```
$ make SHELL="/usr/bin/bash -x" 
+ g++ --help=warnings
+ grep '"-Wfloat-conversion"'
makefile:10: *** "has=".  Stop.
```

**Using `addprefix` and `addsuffix`:**

```
HAS_WARNING = $(shell $(CXX) --help=warnings | grep $(addprefix ",$(addsuffix ",$(1))))
```

Result: No quotes added:

```
$ make SHELL="/usr/bin/bash -x" 
+ g++ --help=warnings
+ grep -Wfloat-conversion
grep: invalid option -- 'W'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
makefile:10: *** "has=".  Stop.
```

---

If I change the search term, to instead only search for `"float-conversion"`, then the grep succeeds:

```
HAS_FLOAT_CONV := $(call HAS_WARNING,float-conversion)
```

Result:

```
$ make SHELL="/usr/bin/bash -x" 
+ g++ --help=warnings
+ grep float-conversion
makefile:10: *** "has=  -Wfloat-conversion          Warn for implicit type conversions that cause loss of floating point precision.".  Stop.
```

However, the pedant in me would like to search for the *whole* warning flag.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can't you prefix the pattern with `-e` or `--` (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2427913/3266847)?

Comment: @BenjaminW. genius!! thank you! :)

Comment: Marked as duplicate so you can close if it's a good match: [How can I grep for a string that begins with a dash/hyphen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427913/how-can-i-grep-for-a-string-that-begins-with-a-dash-hyphen)

Comment: @BenjaminW. done, thanks for the help!